# sort objects in XML and write back into new XML file using C#, LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sorting

I have below XML file, and want to order the objects based on Revision Node and then write ordered objects back into XML file. I have tried LINQ but no luck

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<v1:VNETList xmlns="http://www.xxxxxx.com/NET/eeim" xmlns:v1="http://www.xxxxxx.com/NET/List">
    <Objects> 
         <ID>00-0000-PPP-0001 Template</ID>
        <Object>
          <ID>00-0000-PPP-0001</ID>
           <Revision>2.0</Revision>
          <Name>600-0000-PPP-0001</Name>
          <ClassID>CL_Diagram</ClassID>
          <Association type="is fulfilled by">
            <Object>
              <ID>aae9d_application/pdf</ID>
              <Revision>2.0</Revision>
              <ClassID>FILE</ClassID>
              <Characteristic>
                <Name>InfoType</Name>
                <Value>pdf</Value>
              </Characteristic>                   
            </Object>
          </Association>
          <Characteristic>
            <Name>Status</Name>
            <Value>Historic</Value>
          </Characteristic>
        </Object>
        <Object>
          <ID>00-0000-PPP-0001</ID>
           <Revision>3.0</Revision>
          <Name>00-0000-PPP-0001</Name>
          <ClassID>CL_Diagram</ClassID>
          <Association type="is fulfilled by">
            <Object>
              <ID>090aaead_application/pdf</ID>
              <Revision>3.0</Revision>
              <ClassID>FILE</ClassID>                 
            </Object>
          </Association>
          <Characteristic>
            <Name>Transmittal Number</Name>
            <Value>111111</Value>
          </Characteristic>
          <Characteristic>
            <Name>Is PSI</Name>
            <Value>yes</Value>
          </Characteristic>         
        </Object>
        <Object>
          <ID>00-0000-PPP-0001</ID>          
          <Revision>1.0</Revision>
          <Name>00-0000-PPP-0001</Name>
          <ClassID>CL_Diagram</ClassID>
          <Characteristic>
            <Name>Is Confidential?</Name>
            <Value>False</Value>
          </Characteristic>
          <Characteristic>
            <Name>Is PSI</Name>
            <Value>yes</Value>
          </Characteristic>
        </Object>
    </Objects>
```

I want to order so revision 1 will come first, then 2 and the last will be three. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement objects = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Objects").FirstOrDefault();

            XElement firstObject = objects.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Object").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = firstObject.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<XElement> sortedObjects = objects.Elements(ns + "Object")
                .OrderBy(x => (string)x.Descendants(ns + "Revision").FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList();

            objects.Elements(ns + "Object").Remove();

            objects.Add(sortedObjects);

            doc.Save(FILENAME);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This works well, there is a slight issue, I have namespace at the beginning just before the orders element <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <v1:XXXList xmlns="http://www.EEEEEEE.com/NET/eiwm" xmlns:v1="http://www.EEEEEEE.com/NET/List"> 
<Objects>  if i add namespace it does not work.

Comment: I updated the code.  It is the default namespace that is the issue.  Not the v1 namespace.

Comment: Thanks, that is really help. I guess one final thing, it is now adding namespace for orders and order element. <Objects xmlns=""> 
    <Object xmlns="http://www.xxxxxxx.com/VNET/eiwm">

Comment: That did not change anything, the output is still coming with namespace added to <Objects> and <object>. what is this line supposed to do  XElement firstObject = objects.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Object").FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Why do you want to remove namespaces?  The code works?

Comment: The namespace is required for the target application. I have updated the XML, there was one extra element that I forgot to include, after orders I have <ID>00-0000-PPP-0001 Template</ID>. How can we preserve this element in the updated XML.

Comment: Hi, how can I order in descending order. I want to cast the id into int and order by descending order  .OrderBy(x => (int)x.Descendants(ns + "Revision").FirstOrDefault()) desc

Comment: Change OrderBy to OrderByDescending.

Comment: found a bug, if there are more than 9 objects in XML file, then the ordering does not work as it is treating it as text. so 10,11,12,12 comes before 2. is there a way to treat it as number, i have tried but it does pasre to int as it is an XMLElement. any other option?

Comment: I have parse it to double and it is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can sort the `XML` using `LINQ`

```
XDocument inputxml = XDocument.Load(inputfile);
XDocument outputxml = new XDocument(
                new XElement("Objects.Object",
                    from node in inputxml .Root.Elements()
                    orderby node.Element("Revision").Value
                    select node));
outputxml.Save(outputfile);
```